# Delete data from Timestamp datatype column in Oracle not working

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, sql-delete

I have tried below sql but somehow i am not able to delete or select data. The `CRDT` is `timestamp` datatype and i want to delete data from table where `CRDT = '2021-03-13 14:00:01'`. Below is my sql which is not working:

```
DELETE from TST_EP
where CRDT = TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-03-13 14:00:01');
```

Comment: "Below is my sql which is not working" Not working is not a constructive description of the problem as it does not tell us how it is not working. Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data that replicates your problem; the **FULL** text of the error message; and your expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not explain what "not working" means but, if you are experiencing issues with matching fractional seconds then you can match the down to the nearest second using:

```sql
DELETE FROM TST_EP
WHERE CRDT >= TIMESTAMP '2021-03-13 14:00:01'
AND   CRDT <  TIMESTAMP '2021-03-13 14:00:02';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define "is not working".

I'm *guessing* that you are getting an error message, first because you did not close the single quote around your string representation of a timestamp.

And after you fix that, you need to provide a format mask so that oracle will know how to interpret that string representation of a timestamp'

```
DELETE from TST_EP
where CRDT = TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-03-13 14:00:01','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

If that doesn't fix your problem, then you need to be more explicit about "does not work".

And kudos on using 4-digit year.  I am continually appalled at the number of duh-velopers who continue to recreate the Y2k bug.

Comment: I first tried to select query but no rows retrieved so it does not work...In my table the value is stored in CRDT as '2021-03-13 14:00:01'

Comment: @Symonds - you said `CRDT` is `timestamp` data type. If that is true (is it? How did you check that?) then it is not **stored** as `2021-03-13 14:00:01`. It may be **displayed** that way when you select it, but "stored" refers to how Oracle represents it internally, and it is not as simple as storing it in string representation.

Comment: @EdStevens i am just checking the value in that table ...i really dont understand now why its selecting the rows with the datetimestamp

Comment: its working now with this condition in where clause : trunc(CRDT) =  TO_DATE('2021-03-13','YYYY-MM-DD')

Answer (score 0):

The most probably explanation is that your `TIMESTAMP`has defined with fractional seconds.

Here a small example

```
select crdt from tab;
CRDT               
-------------------
25.03.2021 15:58:48
```

So you have one row in the table with this `TIMESTAMP`, let's try to select it

```
select count(*) from tab
where crdt = TO_TIMESTAMP('25.03.2021 15:58:48','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

Solution is to show the full `TIMESTAMP` with the fractional seconds:

```
select to_char(crdt,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF') crdt from tab;

CRDT                         
-----------------------------
25.03.2021 15:58:48,116000
```

Now when use the complete `TIMESTAMP` you get the match.

```
select count(*) from tab
where crdt = TO_TIMESTAMP('25.03.2021 15:58:48,116000','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF');

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

An other problem could be with the * time zone*, but this should not be your case, as you use the data type `TIMESTAMP`, i.e. *without time zone*.

Comment: i tried like this now but getting error as 'ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string'      Select * from TST_EP
where crdt = TO_TIMESTAMP('13.03.2021 14:00:01,116000','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF');

Comment: can you please show from my example in question how should i do it ?

Comment: @Symonds - the *comma* in Marmite Bomber's answer is "decimal comma" - apparently he must be writing from somewhere in Europe, or some other place that uses decimal comma. It is pretty clear that you are in a location that uses decimal point, not comma - so try again, but use decimal point as in `14:00:01.116000`. Other than that, that was just an **example**. Try to see what you have in YOUR data, by selecting **your** timestamps (from your **table**) with that format model, to see what your actual data (timestamps) looks like.

Comment: yes now there is no errror but unfortunately no rows retrieved...i dont understand why ?

Comment: @Symonds - first run the query without a `where` clause, just to see what timestamps look like in your data. If you are concerned that the table is too big and this will take a lot of time, just add `where rownum <= 30` or something like that. After you confirm that your timestamps have fractional seconds, we can take it from there. But first check to see if that's the case.

Comment: I run this query now select to_char(crdt,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF') crdt from TST_EP;
and it gives error as date format not recognized

Comment: its working now with this condition in where clause : trunc(CRDT) =  TO_DATE('2021-03-13','YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: @Sydmons show us the result of this query: `select DATA_TYPE from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TST_EP' and column_name='CRDT'` I suspect you'll not see `TIMESTAMP` meaning your column is not a *timestamp*